# Combine strings to select column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
books
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         book        |       source     |    store_price   |  bookstore_price |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Batman       |       store      |       10.5       |        9.5       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Superman      |     bookstore    |       null       |         9        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I need to select books and sum prices and my query so far looks like this

```
SELECT
    book,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN source = 'store' then store_price
            WHEN source = 'bookstore' then bookstore_price
        END
    ) AS price
FROM books
GROUP BY 1
;
```

Is it possible to somehow optimize SUM select for ex. `select source||'_price' from books;`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change your design. There is no need for 2 price columns. Use 1 column `price` and then the column `source` is enough to distinguish what kind of price you have.

Comment: this is short version of a complex table view i have and i can not change it ;)

Comment: `with t(book, source, store_price, bookstore_price) as (values('Batman'::text, 'store'::text, 10.5, 9.5), ('Superman', 'bookstore', null, 9)) select *, (to_jsonb(t)->(source||'_price'))::numeric from t;` But it is really bad design IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I"m not 100% sure if this helps, but you can unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select b.book, sum(v.price)
from books b join lateral
     (values ('store', store_price),
             ('bookstore', bookstore_price)
     ) v(source, price)
     on v.source = b.source
group by b.book;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [COALESCE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/) function:

```sql
SELECT
    book,
    source,
    SUM(
        COALESCE(store_price,bookstore_price,0)
    ) AS price
FROM books
GROUP BY 1
;
```

Comment: it will work only if one column is filled, but won't if both

Comment: Yes - if you have more than 1 non-NULL price then you have bad data in the database and will have to either use CASE statements to overcome that or to cleanup the data and put a constraint so that only one of the prices is non-NULL.